# Fully filling in the background-color of an ol list-item

Tags: html, css

[LIVE EXAMPLE ON CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/cLosj)

I would like to have the `background-color: papayawhip;` on `.active` connect with the red bar to the left of the .  What is the best method in accomplishing this.  I would like to maintain the same spacings show in the codepen.

[image: example of what I want to accomplish]

**html**

```
<ol class="meny-control"> 
  <li class="active"><a href="">Potential Apparel</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Facebook + Pillow</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Skatelocal.ly</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Cooking.is</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Foodsters</a></li>
</ol>
```

**SCSS or less**

```
li
  {
      padding: 10px 0;
      margin: 10px 0;
      color: #ccc;
      a
        {
          color: #ccc;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
  }

.active
  {
    position:relative;
    background-color: papayawhip;
    color: #333;

    &:before
      {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: -64px;
        width: 5px;
        background: #f26645;        
      }

    a
      {
        color: #333;   
      }

  }


ol
  {
    list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
    padding-left: 64px;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this for your scss/less:

```
li
  {
      padding: 10px 0;
      margin: 10px 0;
      color: #ccc;
      padding-left: 32px;
      border-left: 5px solid transparent;
      a
        {
          color: #ccc;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
  }

.active
  {
    position:relative;
    background-color: papayawhip;
    color: #333;
    border-left: 5px solid #f26645;
    a
      {
        color: #333;   
      }

  }


ol
  {
    list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;
    list-style-position: inside;
  }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLgqJ

Comment: in fact, if you change the `padding-left` on the `li` element to `26px` the spacing is absolutely identical (although this does depend, of course, on the default padding applied to `ol` elements by the browser -- and you are using a css-reset of some kind, I hope :))